# KDE - how to replace certain text in all Klipper entries

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I have configured Klipper to be limited to 5 entries.

I have a series of text lines which need to be copied and pasted while working with some documents. They are patterned like this:

```
sometext
othertext
name-NNNN.pdf
name-NNNN-text.txt
name-NNNN-other.doc
```

The only thing that changes is the index **NNNN** which is a number from **0001** to **9999**. All other characters stay the same.

Currently I have a temp text file in which I do simple text find-replace for each NNNN and then select and copy all lines 1 by 1, so I can middle-click paste them in the other document. But that is quite time consuming.

How can I configure Klipper so that with some kind of script/action assigned to a shortcut key the **NNNN** is automatically incremented/decremented? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://milianw.de/code-snippets/access-klipper-clipboard-on-cli-under-kde4 I learned how to fill the clipboard with dbus. According to that, you can do the following:

```
tac newclip | while read line; do
   qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper setClipboardContents "$line" >/dev/null
done
```

`newclip` is your temporary file with the clipboard content.

Note that you have to swap the order of input lines (last in - first out), therefore: `tac newclip`.

redirection to /dev/null is done to suppress empty output lines of qdbus.

Hope, that helps a bit...

Comment: I combined your solution with sed and it works. Thanks!